# How do I change order of this multiple integral?

Tags: multiple-integral

The textbook asks me to change the order and then integrate the following integral:

$$\int_0^{\infty}\int_0^x\frac{e^{-y} dy.dx}{y}$$

I am having trouble in changing the order of the integral. Please tell me how to do it, so far I've sketched a curve of $y=x$ and bounding $y=0$, but what after that?

Is $$\int_0^{\infty}\int_y^{\infty}\frac{e^{-y}dx.dy}{y}$$
correct change of order?

Comment: @MarkViola can you please tell me the final answer after integration?

Comment: The integral does not converge.

Comment: @MarkViola Thank you!

Comment: However, the integral $\int_0^\infty \int_x^\infty \frac{e^{-y}}{y}\,dy\,dx$ converges and $$\int_0^\infty \int_x^\infty \frac{e^{-y}}{y}\,dy\,dx=\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-y}}{y}\int_0^y (1)\,dx\,dy=\int_0^\infty e^{-y}\,dy=1$$